# Boost Asio Client Can't Connect to server with selfsigned certificate

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio, self-signed

Im trying to connect to a https server using boost asio as part of a Rest API. However, I can get it. The server has a selfsigned certificate. I disable verification, but then in the handshake it says that the "dh key is too small".

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main(){
    try{
        asio::io_service ioService;
        asio::ssl::context sslContext(asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        
        
        asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
        asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("201.175.33.14", "9005");
        asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpointIterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        
        boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(ioService, sslContext);
        
        ioService.run();
        
        // Enable SSL peer verification.
        socket.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_none);
        SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(socket.native_handle(), "201.175.33.14");
        
        asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpointIterator);
        //------------------------------
        //here is where the program fails 
        socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
        //---------------------------
        boost::asio::streambuf request;
        std::ostream requestStream(&request);
        requestStream << "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        requestStream << "Host: 201.175.33.14\r\n";
        requestStream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        requestStream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        
        asio::write(socket, request);
    }catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

The output is:

handshake: dh key too small

Any ideas on how to solve the problem????
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line

```
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(sslContext.native_handle(),"HIGH:!DH:!aNULL");
```

before connect solved the problem for me.

Comment: Why is this the answer? It seems to have little to do with the certificate being self-signed